# Не знаю как сверстать текст над картинкой. Помогите

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не знаю как сверстать текст над картинкой. Многое пробовал, возможно где-то есть ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста.[image: макет сайта]

```css
header {
  height: 88px;
}

header nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

header nav ul li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 70px 70px;
}

header nav ul li a {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: underline;
}

header hr {
  border: none;
  /* Убираем границу */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Цвет линии */
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Цвет линии для IE6-7 */
  height: 5px;
  /* Толщина линии */
}

article h2 {
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
  font-size: 47.3392px;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 128px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.img {
  text-align: center;
}

div.img img {
  height: 387px;
  width: 944px;
}

article div ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 451px;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 70px 84px;
}

.text_sm {
  font-size: 16px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="row no-gutters">
    <nav class="col-8">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <hr>
  </header>
</div>
<article class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="content row">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>Denis<br> Novik</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3> UX | UI designer <br>24 years old, Minsk</h3>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h2 class="text_sm">RU|ENG</h2>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img class="img-adaptive" src="img/BSPP2266.png">
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так-же как и с меню. Все три элемента надо обвернуть в родителя и родителю дать

```
display: flex;
```

Просто у тебя нет контейнера общего для сайта, который ограничивает ширину для контента сайта